# Best data access method for MVC 3 site with SQL Server backend

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-3, ado.net

I'm building a new website using MVC3 with all data being stored in SQL Server, and I need input in choosing the best data access method.

My priorities are: 
 - Performance (fast processing, low memory/CPU usage)
 - Scalability (easy to grow from 1k to 100k daily users)
 - Extensebility (adding/modifying data structure without tedious changes in multiple places)

Thanks in advance for any input.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with [NHibernate](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/NHibernateForNET) I suppose.....

Answer (score 0):

If this is a new application with a new DEDICATED database then I would take a look at Entity Framework Code First.

If you have an existing database then pick a more traditional ORM tool...

Answer (score 0):

> Scalability (easy to grow from 1k to 100k daily users) - Extensebility (adding/modifying data structure without tedious changes in multiple places)

Sounds like you want the cake and to eat it all too :)

Given the scalability requirements i think you have some very important research to do first before you make your choice.

Be aware that even with an ORM (in my case EF) 'tedious changes', or should i say 'repetitive' maintenance does still occur when you are modifying your schema.

I would look into...

- EF ([code first](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-code-first-walkthrough.aspx) and [model first](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx))
- [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx)
- [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/)

Note that Dapper is a Micro ORM and considered more lightweight than the first 2.  It is also used on this very site.